# distinguishing brackets on the right of an enumeration

Tags: enumerate, brackets

I would like to make a distinguish bracket (as they are used with branched function specifications) on the right side of an enumeration.The bracket should contain the 2 points in the "itemize".

Has someone a hint how to do it?

```
\begin{itemize}

\item Für einen \textbf{Hochpunkt H} (lokales Maximum) gelten:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $f'(x_H) = 0$ (notwendige Bedingung: waagrechte Tangente)
        \item $f''(x_H) < 0$ (Rechtskurve)
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a one-off situation, this seems to do what's needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Für einen \textbf{Hochpunkt H} (lokales Maximum) gelten:\vspace{\parsep}

  \!\!$\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\begin{minipage}{0.87\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $f'(x_H) = 0$ (notwendige Bedingung: waagrechte Tangente)
        \item $f''(x_H) < 0$ (Rechtskurve)
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}\right\}=xy$

\item Für einen \textbf{Hochpunkt H} (lokales Maximum) gelten:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item $f'(x_H) = 0$ (notwendige Bedingung: waagrechte Tangente)
        \item $f''(x_H) < 0$ (Rechtskurve)
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]